# Cannot add tracks for 2D Stabilization

Tags: movie-clip-editor

I'm unable to add `Tracks For Location` or `Tracks For Rotation / Scale` in v2.79. The `+` button is greyed out. Why would that be?

[image: 2D stabilization panel]

I opened my video file in the `Movie Clip Editor`, added a few markers, tracked them, ticked `Display Stabilization` and `2D Stabilization` and `Autoscale`.

It was suggested in the comments that I should click first "solve". None of the video tutorials that I saw on YouTube indicated that I should so that, though. I ticked "Tripod" under "Solve" and then clicked "Solve Object Motion". It made no difference.

[image]

Comment: You can only add the currently active/selected tracks. Make sure that you have selected something

Comment: They are selected. Could it have something to do with the tracking settings for each marker?

Comment: Upload the file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: Have you performed a solve yet? Even a tripod solve

Comment: I added the blender file and performed the solve. No change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tracks created for camera can be used for stabilization.

[image]

1. Select markers and copy them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. Select (in <kbd>N</kbd> side properties panel): **Objects** -> **Camera**
3. Paste markers here <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
4. Now you can use copied markers for stabilization

Comment: So there are different types of tracks. Good to know.